# Feynman: 'The “average time until the next collision” is obtained in the usual way:'

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, diffusion

In [The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol I 43-1](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_43.html#Ch43-S1) Feynman says

> The “average time until the next collision” is obtained in the usual way: 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \text{Average time until the next collision} =
> \frac{1}{N_0}\int_0^\infty t\,\frac{N(t)\,dt}{\tau}.
> \end{equation*}

Since this is "the usual way" I guess I should be ashamed to ask how this equation is established.  Feynman suggest carying out the integration to show that it works, which I did, as shown in the screen scrape below.  But that doesn't really explain the reason for the form Feynman gives.

Is there a more informative way of establishing the formula given by Feynman?

[image]

Comment: See also the notes http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4106-18-Fall/Notes-PP.pdf for the Poisson process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $p$, given by
$$p(t) = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau},$$
is the probability density for the time between collisions to be $t$. That is, the probability that the time between collisions is between $t$ and $t+\Delta t$ is given by
$$p(t)\Delta t = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}\Delta t.$$
Once the probability distribution is established, we compute an average value in the usual way, i.e.
$$\langle t \rangle = \int_0^{\infty}dt~t~p(t)
=\int_0^{\infty}dt~t\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}
=\frac{1}{N_0}\int_0^{\infty}dt~t\frac{N_0}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}.$$

---

By "usual way", I'm referencing a standard result from probability theory that the average value of a random variable $x$ with corresponding probability distribution $p(x)$ is given by
$$\langle x \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx~xp(x).$$
This is likely easier to see in the context of *discrete* random variables, where the possible values of $x$ are $x_i$, and then the average value of $x$ is the sum over the possible values weighted by their respective probabilities, i.e.
$$\langle x \rangle =\sum_ix_ip(x_i).$$
(The discrete and continous versions are clearly analogous.)
To understand *this* result, imagine that we performed measurements of $x$ and got the outcome $x_i$ a number $n_i$ of times. Then, the average of this set of measurements is just
$$\langle x \rangle=\frac{\mbox{sum of all measurements}}{\mbox{number of measurements}},$$
which can be written as
$$\langle x \rangle=\frac{1}{N}\sum_ix_in_i,$$
where $N$ is the total number of measurements. Then, we write this as
$$\langle x \rangle=\sum_ix_if_i,$$
where
$$f_i = \frac{n_i}{N},$$
is the *frequency* of outcome $x_i$.  In the limit as we take many, many measurements, this frequency can be interpreted (under the somewhat problematic *frequentist* interpretation of probability) as the probability of outcome $x_i$ occurring.

Comment: That was, indeed, the "hook" I was looking for. 

 May I suggest adding that Feynman gives us the probability $P\left(t\right)=\mathit{e}^{-t/\tau}$ *(eq. 43.8)* of a particle going collision-free for a period $t$. So the probability of it having a collision in the time interval $\left[t,t+dt\right]$ will be the negative of $dP\left(t\right)=-\frac{1}{\tau}\mathit{e}^{-t/\tau}dt=-p\left(t\right),$  which is your $p$?   That is, if you agree with my reasoning.  If not, please correct me.

Comment: Make that $dP\left(t\right)=-\frac{1}{\tau}\mathit{e}^{-t/\tau}dt=-p\left(t\right)dt$

Comment: While typing this up for my notes, I realized I don't understand why $\langle t \rangle = \int_0^{\infty}dt~t~p(t)$ will be the average time until the next collision.  In my experience, a formula for an average typically has a numerator and a denominator.   My own muddled reasoning was that $N_0 \tau=T$ is the time by which we can assume all particles have experienced a collision.

Comment: Probabilities can't be negative. If $p(t)d t$ is the probability of there being *no* collision in the interval $[t,t+dt]$, then the probability of a collision occurring in the same interval is $1-p(t)dt$. As for why $\int_0^{\infty} tp(t)dt$ is the average value of $t$: this is a standard result from probability theory. Basically, an average is equal to the sum over the a possible outcome times its probability. For discrete (instead of continuous) possible outcomes, the average is $\sum_i x_i p(x_i)$.

Comment: I've added a section on probability to make the answer self-contained.

Comment: $dP\left(t\right)$ is the change in probability. And the probability $P(t)$ of a particle going without a collision is a decreasing function of time.

Comment: I'm not sure that "change in probability" is a very meaningful phrase. Note that $dP = \frac{dP}{dt}dt = p(t) dt$, which is the probability of no collision occurring in $[t,t+dt]$, in which case $P(t) = \int_0^{\infty} p(t')dt'$ is the probability that no collision occurs in the interval $[0,t]$. Finally, therefore, $1-P(t)$ will be the probability that a collision *does* occur in the interval $[0,t]$.

Comment: We are tracking one specific particle. $P\left(t\right)$ is the probability of that particle going collision-free for a period $t$. $P\left(t+dt\right)$ is the probability that will remain collision free for a period $t+dt$, which is smaller than $P\left(t\right)$.  $P\left(t+dt\right)-P\left(t\right)=dP<0$.  That difference is the contrapositive of the probability that there will be a collision in the interval $\left(t,t+dt\right)$.  This is not the same as trying to predict the next coin toss based on previous tosses.

Answer (score 1):

Feynman derives an expression for the probability that the molecule survives for a time $t$ **without** a collision as $P(t)=\exp(-t/τ)$, ie the probability a particle, during a time interval of $t$, not colliding with anything.

At $t$ increases the probability of such an event (no collision) decreases which is what one would expect.

From the probability function one can find the average time before a collision $\langle t \rangle$.

$$\langle t \rangle =\dfrac{\int ^\infty_0 t \; \exp(t/\tau)\; dt}{\int ^\infty_0  \; \exp(t/\tau)\; dt} = \tau$$

which is the same as that introduced by Feynman except that I have chosen not to add an $N_0$ top and bottom of the equation.